# Increase the font size of the floating language panel

Tags: fonts, language-support, appearance

I'm looking to increase the font size only for the floating language panel (for selecting characters in non-European fonts).  I don't want my main default font larger, but I do want to see more detail in character selection specific to the floating language panel.

How can I make only this bigger, and keep the rest of my fonts the same size?

[image: le4]

Comment: What is your OS??

Comment: I think this is very specific, and you should consult the certain pinyin input developer. It was coded in the pinyin input software.